# Smooth conics in linear subspaces of $S^2U^*$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $U$ be some $3$-dimensional vector space over some field $\mathbb{k}$. It is possible to consider the projective space $\mathbb{P}(S^2U^*)$ as a space of conics on the projective plane $\mathbb{P}_2=\mathbb{P}(U)$. Given two quadratic forms $q_1,q_2\in S^2(U^*)$ we can build the subspace in $\mathbb{P}(S^2U^*)$ consisting of $\lambda q_1+\mu q_2$ for all $(\lambda:\mu)\in \mathbb{P}_1$ (it can be identified if the projective line). I'd like to find some easy way to get the number of singular conics in this family.
First, we can choose same base $(e_0,e_1,e_2)$ in $U$ and build two matrices $A$ and $B$ which are Gram matrices of $q_1$ and $q_2$ respectively. Then $\lambda q_1+\mu q_2$ is singular if and only if $\mathrm{det}(\lambda A+\mu B)=0$. Thus we get a homogeneous form of degree three (because three is the size of $A$ and $B$) and it has $0$ (only if our field is not closed), $1$,$2$ or $3$ zeros in the projective line.
So, could you give me some recipe to understand how many singular conics we can get? Perhaps, each $p(\lambda,\mu)=p\in S^2U^*$ can be presented as $\mathrm{det}(\lambda A+\mu B)$ for some symmetric $A$ and $B$ and thus we can always get $1,2$ or $3$ singular conics?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. As you say, singular conics in this family (called a _pencil_) correspond exactly to zeroes of the homogeneous form $det(\lambda A + \mu B)$, so there are at most 3 (exactly 3, if we count with multiplicity).

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to understand if there can be exactly 1,2 or 3 distinct singular conics.

Comment: OK, it wasn't completely clear to me that was what you were asking. In that case, I claim the answer is yes: you can get any of those as the number of singular conics; if your field is not algebraically closed, it might also be that there are _no_ singular members of the pencil defined over $k$. I think that convincing yourself of these facts is really just a matter of playing around with the choices of $A$ and $B$, and seeing what you get.